# how to pass variables from a temp struct variable for multiple struct variables (permanent storage)

Tags: c++, struct

I got this code here in C++ whose main task is to calculate the difference between two times. First it's supposed to assign values to two struct variables. Afterwards its supposed to find out which one of the times starts first. The last thing it will do is to calculate the difference between the times.

My problem with this code is not that I can't pass variables from one temp struct variable to another variable, the problem is when I pass a second time from the temp struct variable to the second struct variable, the variables from the first struct variable becomes forgotten by the program. Is there anyway to let the variables passed to be in a struct variable permanently?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int maxAddTime = 141; // 23 hours + 59 min. + 59 sec.
const int minAddTime = 0;
int addTime;

char choice;

bool done = false;

struct timeset {
   int hour;
   int minute;
   int second;
};

int main(){
    timeset time1, time2, temp;
   do {                  
     int times = 1;
        while (times <=2) {
            do {
            cout << "Write your " << times << " time (hh mm ss)" << endl;
            temp = (times == 1) ? time1 : time2;
            cin >> temp.hour >> temp.minute >> temp.second;
            int addTime = temp.hour + temp.minute + temp.second;

            if ( addTime < minAddTime || addTime > maxAddTime) {
               cout << "Invalid time!" << endl;
               cout << "Do you want to change the time? (Y)es or (N)o?" << endl;
               cin >> choice;
            }
            else { 
               choice = 'n'; 
               times++;

            }

            if (times == 1){
            time1 = temp;
            cout << time1.minute ;
            }
            else {
            time2 = temp;
            cout << time2.minute << endl;
            }

            break;
            }
            while ( choice != 'n' || choice != 'N');
         }   

      if (time1.hour > time2.hour || time1.minute > time2.minute ||
          time1.second > time2.second) {        
         cout << "The first time comes first!\n";
      }
      else if ( time1.hour < time2.hour || time1.minute < time2.minute || 
                time1.second < time2.second) {
             cout << "The second time comes first!\n";
      }
      else {
         cout << "The times are equal!\n";
      }

      int addTime =  time1.hour + time1.minute + time1.second;
      cout << addTime << endl;
      addTime = addTime - (time2.hour + time2.minute + time2.second);

      cout << addTime << endl << endl;
   }
   while (!done);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I use a temp because I want to have less duplicate in the code. This is the process I want time1 -> temp -> time1, time2 -> temp -> time2 What the program is doing is this: time1 -> temp -> time1, time1 -> some high variables, time2 -> temp -> time2

Answer (score 1):

You are incrementing "times" before your are checking its value:

```
 else { 
               choice = 'n'; 
               times++;

            }
```

So, when you get here after the first input, times is already set to 2, and the first condition will never be met.  Move the times++ to the end of the loop;

```
    if (times == 1){
    time1 = temp;
    cout << time1.minute ;
    }
    else {
    time2 = temp;
    cout << time2.minute << endl;
    }

    /// other code
    times++;
```

In addition, you cannot simply add different time unit together (hr+mins+sec) and get any meaningful result.  You need to normalize each time component to a common unit - seconds would be the most likely.  So, calculate as:

```
int addTime =  time1.hour*60*60 + time1.minute*60 + time1.second;
```

Comment: I was struggling with the first part so I didn't completely had the time to continue on the third part, but I have you know I was going to do it! I'm going to try this now! Thank you so much :^D               - IT WERKS!